# Counting characters excluding spaces in C using while loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to count the number of characters the user has as an input using a while loop, but for some reason the output counts always one more than the expected value. ( I'm a newbie so please don't hate me for it.)

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int len,i;
    char sttr[29];
    fgets(sttr,29,stdin);
    len = 0;
        i=0;
        while(sttr[i] != '\0'){
        if (sttr[i] != ' '){
            len++;
        }
        i++;

    }
   printf("%d\n",len);

}
```

Comment: [A `fgets` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) could be useful. And the (probable) problem should have been mentioned by just about any book or tutorial that mentions `fgets`.

Comment: If you want to only count printable characters excluding white-space characters, you can use `isgraph`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fgets` function reads in a line of text and stores that text, **including the newline** if there's room for it.

So the output is one more because of the newline.

Comment: So, if I give the input "John" does that mean the input would actually be "John\n\0" ? I just used fgets() instead of scanf() because scanf doesn't read a blank space and didn't know much about fgets(). Thanks!

Comment: yes.  In your code when you used `fgets()` **before** your `while` loop, you captured the `\n` character in `sttr`.  Then your while loop counts **anything** other than a `' '` because you told it to, so it counted the `\n` character in addition to `"John".

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a newbie so

it should be worth mentioning that your `while` loop finishing is **completely relying** upon the fact that the null character `\0` is found in `sttr[]`.

Because you use the function `fgets()` it will automatically append a `\0` character after the input is stored in `sttr[]` so it is likely to never be a problem, but...

realize under different circumstances if you were to parse a string like that there is likely to be a much greater chance that the while loop could become an infinite loop because it never found a `\0` character to terminate.

so something like this for example would be more robust:

*don't assume a null character will always be present in your string*

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# define MAX 29

int main ( void )
{
    int len, i;
    char sttr[MAX];

    fgets( sttr, MAX, stdin );

    len = 0;
    i = 0;

    /* make sure i does not index past sttr[MAX] */
    while ( ( sttr[i] != '\0') && ( i < MAX ) )
    {
        if ( sttr[i] != ' ' )
        {
            len++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` *does* assure it gets terminated by a `0`. I'd be more concerned about not testing its return value.